# Example code for logging to HDF5 file in C#?

Tags: c#, hdf5

I have been looking at the C# wrapper for HDF5 and it is seriously lacking in decent C# examples. Does anyone have any simple example code for logging scientific data to file?

I want to write a timestamp, with some string, int and floating point values.

The code should **create** the file, initialise the dataset and then **write** some data.

ie:

20120101 23:12:54.1234 ABC 1111 123.4 567.8 987.6 654.3

...

...

...

I am looking at HDF5 as I need high speed and want to store large amounts of data. I don't want to write directly to a database. The idea is that this can be parsed at a later date and then written to the database if necessary.

Comment: did you look into http://hdf5.net/ ?

Comment: Yes, I should have mentioned the C# wrapper I am talking about is hdf5.net.